# Error 2602: The [2] table entry '[3]' has no associated entry in the Media table.The [2] table entry '[3]' has no associated entry in the Media table

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, installshield-2012

I have created a multi instance application with installshield 2014. While the base instance is getting installed without any issue, I am getting the "Error 2602:The File table entry '.Primary_' has no associated entry in the Media table." while installing it's first instance i.e. the instanceID1.msi. 
Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to troubleshoot.

Comment: I am trying to create  a multi instance msi with which i will be able to install different instances of the same application. Here are the steps, I have followed:

Comment: -Added a basic Msi of IS 2014 to my existing solution(calculator for demo purpose) in VS 2012.
-In the Project Assistant window>> Application Files>> Added the Project Output.
-In Installation Manager>>Media>>Release>>Product Configuration>>Multiple Instance>>Added a new instance named '1'.
-Built the solution.
-Now, when I am trying to install the base instance, It is getting installed Properly.
-But when I am trying to install the instanceId1 i.e. the first instance, I am getting the error: "The File table entry 'msiname.Primary_' has no associated entry in the media table."

Comment: @ Christopher Painter
Being the expert on these subjects do you think there is any issue with my apporach. Currently I am trying to install them manually i.e. C:\Users\920841\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\CalculatorInstaller\CalculatorInstaller\Express\DVD-5\DiskImages\DISK1 and for running the instance, I am going to the instance folder  and then running it from there. I am on allout search to find thefix but no success yet. Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you can post source code to a minimal example that reproduces the problem I can debug it for you.

Comment: I had the idea of installing the msi & it's instances silently through msiexec.exe in cmd. that is why,Instead of installing from setup.exe, I was trying to install the base and the instance msi from individual  folders and that is why i was getting the error. But instead i used the following command and it worked for me.

Comment: Setup.exe instance=<instance ID>/v"/l*v c:\test.log" /v"MYPROPERTY1=value1" /v"/qb"
Thank you Christopher for being there for help!